# Android keep send information to server

Tags: android, audio-fingerprinting

I built a similar app Shazam, however it only works in sending an entire file of 10seconds of audio.

My doubt is: In android, there's any thing to keep like Shazam of while music is playing and the database is searching? Or it's own Shazam service technology?

Comment: What you could do is try to match a smaller piece of audio while listening. Like this: after 2s, send the first 2s and try to match. If does not match, after 3s, send 3s, and so on, until it matches or passes 10s without match. It can consume resources, but you can fine tune, sending every 2s, every 3s, etc

Answer (score 0):

Shazam developed that audio fingerprint matching technlogy. It's not available in the default Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The Shazam technology is proprietary. The [base algorithm was documented](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Wang03-shazam.pdf) since by its creator:

> The algorithm uses a combinatorially hashed time-frequency constellation analysis of the 
>   audio, yielding unusual properties such as transparency, in which multiple tracks mixed together may each be identified.

This is very novel and efficient, but the principles for fingerprinting audio stay the same. Among which certainly a FTT (fast fourier transform) to at least detect the BPM. Its even possible to convert sound to an image (the simplest being a spectogram), which can be further processed by audio-unrelated software.

If you need an audio analysis library, written in Java you could look into [MusicG](https://code.google.com/p/musicg/) for example which is said to be simple to use on Android.

Comment: I'm using the musicg already, but he's only works if you send an entire file. And not by default in shazam, that while the music is playing and their database is searching together.